# Augmenting the basic types (from JavaScript: The Good Parts) - why is the value of 'this' returned?

Tags: javascript, this

On page 33 the author shows a trick to avoid typing 'prototype' when adding new methods to the basic types, followed by an example that extracts the integer portion of a number.

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this; // removal of this line still yields the same result
};

Number.method('integer', function () {
    return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceil' : 'floor'](this);
});

console.log((-10 / 3).integer());
```

The output is -3 as expected, even if I comment out the line that returns `this`. What does this line accomplish?

Comment: It's probably, so you can chain `.method(/*...*/).method(/*...*/)`, but i am quite confused, why any of this would be desired anyways

Comment: Note that this is a *weird* approach to setting prototypes and, while it attempts to make life easier, it is slow and clunky compared to just using [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) which weren't around when that book was written).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns the prototype object when you call `Number.method(...)` which would allow you to chain it: `Number.method(...).method(...)`.

Since your code ignores the return value when you call the `method` method, changing that return value has no effect.